Does a sortable Sprig 'board' need to use a table structure for full functionality?
I am experimenting with a sortable 'board' of project entries, based on the excellent Sprigboard videos by @ben-croker.
It seems to be working so far with a flex-based structure ( I can sort flex rows by date and title so far), but Im curious to know if theres any Sprig functionality that I might lose as I get further into this by not building this in a table-based structure?
thanks for any thoughts and time :)

No, Sprig is entirely flexible and does not impose specific requirements on your markup. While using a table might be better in contexts where the data is best represented in that format, you won’t miss out on any Sprig features or functionality if you choose to implement it using flex.

thanks @revlis, good to hear...
